# Why am I getting different results when using for and while loops?

Tags: c#, for-loop, while-loop

Why am I getting different results when using for and while loops?

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i*= 2)
{
    Console.Write(i);
}

//1248163264
```

.

```
int i = 1;
while (i < 100)
{
    i *= 2;
    Console.Write(i);
}

//248163264128
```

Comment: This would be a *great* thing to use to learn about the debugger and debugging.  The "problem" and code are so simple you can focus on the tools available.

Comment: Have a look at the order in which you write and increment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `for` loop the condition is checked each time after the step (`i *= 2`) is evaluated.Since it evalutes to `false` when `i` becomes `128`, the loop ends.

But in `while`, your `Console.WriteLine` is executed before the check.So that's why it outputs one extra number...

Answer (score 5):

Because `while` statement executes your `Console.Write(128)` first and then checks it if `i` (which is `128` in this case) is less than `100` or not.

if you use `Console.Write(i);` before you multiple it, you will get the same result because in this case it writes your `64` value first then multiple by `2` and since `128 < 100` returns `false`, it will not execute in your while statement anymore.

```
int i = 1;
while (i < 100)
{
    Console.Write(i);
    i *= 2;
} // 1248163264
```

Read [8.8.1 The `while` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664751%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> A while statement is executed as follows:
>
> - The boolean-expression (Section 7.16) is evaluated.
> - If the Boolean expression yields true, control is transferred to the embedded statement. When and if control reaches the end point of
>     the embedded statement (possibly from execution of a continue
>     statement), control is transferred to the beginning of the while
>     statement.
> - If the Boolean expression yields false, control is transferred to the end point of the while statement.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have placed the increment in a different place than how the `for` loop does it. To do it the same way, you should have the increment last in the loop:

```
int i = 1;
while (i < 100)
{
  Console.Write(i);
  i *= 2;
}
```

Note: The actual output from your while loop was `248163264128`, not `1248163264128`. Notice that there is no `1` in the beginning, as you are increasing the value to `2` before the first output.

Answer (score 2):

proper conversion:

```
for(initialization,condition,increment)
{data}
```

to convert this from to while you have to do this:

```
initialization
while(condition)
{
data
increment
}
```

you have interchanged the lines in while thats why you are getting wrong results